# StackOverflow Tags Predictor…Suggest an Machine Learning Approach please?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, text-classification

I am trying to predict tags for stackoverflow questions and I am not able to decide which Machine Learning algorithm will be a correct approach for this.

**Input:** As a dataset I have mined stackoverflow questions, I have tokenized the data set and removed stopwords and punctuation from this data.

**Things i have tried:**

1. TF-IDF
2. Trained Naive Bayes on the dataset and then gave user defined input to predict tags, but its not working correctly
3. Linear SVM

Which ML algorithm I should use Supervised or Unsupervised? If possible please, suggest a correct ML approach from the scratch. PS: I have the list of all tags present on StackOverflow so, will this help in anyway? Thanks

Comment: Not possible to also get the tags, then split the set in 2 parts, train with 1 part, verify with the other?

Comment: Already doing that in Naive Bayes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try MLP. In order to begin I would choose a reasonably small set of keywords for input and encode them [1..100 for example] and train for a reasonably small set of output tags.

PS: Unsupervised learning for this task is unfavorable in general because many questions that refer to different tags have very similar content and are very likely to get clustered together.